# How to remove textarea which id was assigned as variable using flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have different textarea in a application and these have different Ids, once user move cursor inside in the specific textarea, delete button activate and it execute a function to remove this item, the Id of the textarea assigned as string variable, In this case how could i delete the component from Canvas.

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to post some code to explain better what you mean.

Comment: Hi Peter
Thanks for your response. here is my code, Here i use the delete function as
public function deleteWidget(objName:String):void
{
this.removeElement(objName as IVisualElement); 
}

And below there are few textareas

<s:TextArea id="headerText" text="Header Text" mouseDown="selectText(event)" />
  
<s:TextArea id="contentText" text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" mouseDown="selectText(event)" />

Where the function is passing the id headerText or contentText from parent application, but it is not deleting the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
public function deleteWidget(objName:String):void { 
  this.removeElement(objName as IVisualElement); 
}
```

Instead, you should be passing the reference to the object:

```
public function deleteWidget(obj:IVisualElement):void { 
  this.removeElement(obj); 
}
```

Or, if (for some reason) you *must* pass a only the Id as a String then, you still need to obtain a reference to the actual object. Maybe something like:

```
public function deleteWidget(objName:String):void { 
  this.removeElement(this.getChildByName(objName) as IVisualElement); 
}
```